# My Program breaks randomly

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random, numbers

My program randomly decides to quit working. No Error messages, just pressing the play buttom with nothing happens, and I check my card summary to find that The QuantityInteger to a corresponding player subtracted a card and added to discard pile, but didn't add a new card to their hand. However that is completely random as it works or doesn't work in randomly intervals.

T is sort of the heart of my code. Currently I only implemented it for two player mode. If T = 0 then it executes the code for player 1, if T = 1 it executes code for player 2.

The ChecksDynamic represents what the range will be on the For Loop, as those numbers represent the numbers valid to that players spot in the array.

The Atk Dialog represents which player you decide to attack.( can only atk one person in 2 player mode since you can't attack yourself).

T also places the different players quantity integers into a use case. The output variable of the usecase = player Assign to that specfic value of T.

Then I convert all players cards using a use case to make my code dynamic for the checkboxes checked for a specific player.

The If statement then sees if the checkbox is checked, and the quantity integer to the right player (SelectPlayer from the select case) is selected.

Then the hitpoints are subtracted based on card damage value.

If a card is a weapon the player has the option to keep the card or discard it.
If not discard nothing changes besides hitpoints.

In the GrabFromDeckandDiscard procedure I use T with a Select Case again to subract from the correct players item inventory

Then it adds the corresponding card to the discard pile

Then I run a function to randomly pick a card that is available in the deckgroup's quantity integer.
I run the Select case again to then add the need card from the randomly generated number to the corresponding players inventory.

Then the last major part involves switching T to the next value. For testing purposes I put a random label on my form, and use it to see the value of T. T doesn't seem to be failing from what I can tell.

```
Private Sub PlayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
        Dim HitPoints() As Label = {Nothing, HitPoints1, HitPoints2, HitPoints3, HitPoints4, HitPoints5}
        Dim n, SelectPlayer As Integer
        Label1.Text = T.ToString
        'Player 1
        If T = 0 And (CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked = True) Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = False
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
            ChecksDynamicA = 0
            ChecksDynamicB = 4
            'Player 2
        ElseIf T = 1 And (CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked = True) Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = False
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
            ChecksDynamicA = 5
            ChecksDynamicB = 9
            'Player 3
        ElseIf T = 2 And (CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked = True) Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = False
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
            ChecksDynamicA = 10
            ChecksDynamicB = 14
            'Player 4
        ElseIf T = 3 And (CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked = True) Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = False
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
            ChecksDynamicA = 15
            ChecksDynamicB = 19
            'Player 5
        ElseIf T = 4 And (CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked = True Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked = True) Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = False
            ChecksDynamicA = 20
            ChecksDynamicB = 24
        End If
        'Code for choosing which player to attack
        AtkPlayerDialog.ShowDialog()
        If AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = 1 Then
            n = 1
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = 2 Then
            n = 2
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = 3 Then
            n = 3
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = 4 Then
            n = 4
        ElseIf AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult = 5 Then
            n = 5
        End If
        'CheckedLoop
        For Me.Checks = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB
            'Supplement Numbers(1-5) variable in loop
                NumberChecks = NumberArray(Checks)
            'Select the Player
            Select Case T
                Case 0
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger
                Case 1
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger2
                Case 2
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger3
                Case 3
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger4
                Case 4
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger5
            End Select
            'Convert arrays to correct textboxes
            Select Case Checks
                Case 0, 5, 10, 15, 20
                    TextBoxInteger = 0
                Case 1, 6, 11, 16, 21
                    TextBoxInteger = 1
                Case 2, 7, 12, 17, 22
                    TextBoxInteger = 2
                Case 3, 8, 13, 18, 23
                    TextBoxInteger = 3
                Case 4, 9, 14, 19, 24
                    TextBoxInteger = 4
            End Select
            'Play Card(s)
            If CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Checked = True AndAlso SelectPlayer > 0 Then
                'Subtract Hitpoints when damage is delt
                Player1HandGroup(n).HitPoints -= Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).DamageInteger
                HitPoints(n).Text = Player1HandGroup(n).HitPoints.ToString
                'When player plays hand, card quantity is removed from hand to the discard pile.
                If Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).CardType = "Weapon" Then
                    DiscardDialog.ShowDialog()
                    'Choose if to Discard Weapon after usage
                    If DiscardDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
                    End If
                Else
                    Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
                End If
            End If

            ChecksLabel.Text = Checks.ToString
        Next

        Dim CardCheckBoxInteger As Integer
        'Clear Check Boxes when turn is finished
        For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
            CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Checked = False
        Next

        'Turn off play button
        PlayButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
        'ReDeclare CheckBox Array for Private sub
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
        'Discard
        Select Case T
            Case 0
                Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger -= 1
            Case 1
                Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger2 -= 1
            Case 2
                Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger3 -= 1
            Case 3
                Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger4 -= 1
            Case 4
                Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger5 -= 1
        End Select
        'Add Card to Discard Pile
        DiscardGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger += 1
        'Shuffle Deck from Discard Pile if Deck is out of cards
        Call DiscardPile()
        'Reset Number Generator, unless weapon isn't discard
        Dim validDeckGroupsIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
        For ndx As Integer = 0 To (DeckGroup.Count - 1)
            If DeckGroup(ndx).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
                validDeckGroupsIndexes.Add(ndx)
            End If
        Next ndx
        Dim deckGroupNdx As Integer = Rnd.Next(0, validDeckGroupsIndexes.Count)
        Number = DeckGroup(deckGroupNdx).ID

        If DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
            'Grab New Card From Deck
            DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
            Select Case T
                Case 0
                    Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger += 1
                Case 1
                    Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger2 += 1
                Case 2
                    Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger3 += 1
                Case 3
                    Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger4 += 1
                Case 4
                    Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger5 += 1
            End Select
            ' assign card type to chosen card and assign "number" to corresponding cards number as well
            CardTypeArray(Checks) = Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
            NumberArray(Checks) = Number
        End If
        'Switch to next player
        Select Case T
            Case 0
                For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                    Select Case CardCheckBoxInteger
                        Case 0
                            n = 5
                        Case 1
                            n = 6
                        Case 2
                            n = 7
                        Case 3
                            n = 8
                        Case 4
                            n = 9
                    End Select
                    CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(n)).CardNameString
                Next
                T += 1
            Case 1
                If GameSize = 2 Then
                    For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                        CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(CardCheckBoxInteger)).CardNameString
                    Next CardCheckBoxInteger
                    T -= 1
                End If
                If GameSize > 2 Then
                    T += 1
                End If
            Case 2
            Case 3
            Case 4

        End Select
        Label1.Text = T.ToString
    End Sub
```

Comment: As a note, you don't need to check `If CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked = True`. Only `If CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked` is sufficient.

Comment: Could you distill what your program does into a 1 sentence summary? The second sentence made me think it was a media player, the third solitaire, then by the next few paragraphs I gave up.

Comment: Also, what part "breaks"? Do you get exceptions or something? If so, a stack-trace would be more than helpful.

Comment: Where is `T` defined?

Comment: T is defined at the modular level. Once again thanks for the improvements you did for my code. it functions the same, but it sure makes everything a lot easier to read. I still haven't found the cause yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution will be easier to find if you clean up your code. For example, here are at least 20 lines removed by just a cursory glance.

```
    Private Sub PlayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click
        Dim CardCheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {CardCheckBox1, CardCheckBox2, CardCheckBox3, CardCheckBox4, CardCheckBox5}
        Dim HitPoints() As Label = {Nothing, HitPoints1, HitPoints2, HitPoints3, HitPoints4, HitPoints5}
        Dim n, SelectPlayer As Integer
        Label1.Text = T.ToString
        'Player 1
        If CardCheckBoxArray(0).Checked Or CardCheckBoxArray(1).Checked Or CardCheckBoxArray(2).Checked Or CardCheckBoxArray(3).Checked Or CardCheckBoxArray(4).Checked Then
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = Not (0=T)
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = Not (1=T)
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = Not (2=T)
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = Not (3=T)
            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = Not (4=T)
            ChecksDynamicA = 5 * T
            ChecksDynamicB = 5 * T + 4
        End If
        'Code for choosing which player to attack
        AtkPlayerDialog.ShowDialog()
        n = AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult
        'CheckedLoop
        For Me.Checks = ChecksDynamicA To ChecksDynamicB
            'Supplement Numbers(1-5) variable in loop
            NumberChecks = NumberArray(Checks)
            'Select the Player
            Select Case T
                Case 0
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger
                Case 1
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger2
                Case 2
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger3
                Case 3
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger4
                Case 4
                    SelectPlayer = Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).QuantityInteger5
            End Select
            'Convert arrays to correct textboxes
            TextBoxInteger = Checks Mod 5
            'Play Card(s)
            If CardCheckBoxArray(TextBoxInteger).Checked AndAlso SelectPlayer > 0 Then
                'Subtract Hitpoints when damage is delt
                Player1HandGroup(n).HitPoints -= Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).DamageInteger
                HitPoints(n).Text = Player1HandGroup(n).HitPoints.ToString
                'When player plays hand, card quantity is removed from hand to the discard pile.
                If Player1HandGroup(NumberChecks).CardType.Equals("Weapon") Then
                    DiscardDialog.ShowDialog()
                    'Choose if to Discard Weapon after usage
                    If DiscardDialog.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
                    End If
                Else
                    Call GrabFromDeckAndDiscard()
                End If
            End If

            ChecksLabel.Text = Checks.ToString
        Next

        Dim CardCheckBoxInteger As Integer
        'Clear Check Boxes when turn is finished
        For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
            CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Checked = False
        Next

        'Turn off play button
        PlayButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

And this one!

```
            For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                Select Case CardCheckBoxInteger
                    Case 0
                        n = 5
                    Case 1
                        n = 6
                    Case 2
                        n = 7
                    Case 3
                        n = 8
                    Case 4
                        n = 9
                End Select
                CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(n)).CardNameString
            Next
```

Turn into:

```
            For CardCheckBoxInteger = 0 To 4
                CardCheckBoxArray(CardCheckBoxInteger).Text = Player1HandGroup(NumberArray(CardCheckBoxInteger+5)).CardNameString
            Next
```

Comment: Thank You. I'll test it when I get off work. I'll see what happens from there.

Comment: Ok I think I may have diagnoised the problem partially. The code works as expected when I have a weapon in my hand and I choose not to discard it. When a weapon card is chosen not to be discarded the code basically ends there and the GrabFromDeckAndDiscard Sub Procedure is not executed because there is no need to generate a new number to represent a change in card. This tells me that the error is very likely somewhere in the GrabFromDeckAndDiscard Sub-Procedure.

Comment: I Removed the NumberChecks Variable. It works the same when I just use the number array with the checks variable in place of where i had numberchecks. I think I may have found the broken function problem. Randomly an item will subtract from the correct Quantity Integer, however does not add a new card from the deck/subtract from deck. Now my task is to find out what is causing the number not to do as such. Which Leads me to believe it may be something to do with the random number generator.

Comment: May the force be with you.